# Graylog: which tag triggers the message collection?

Tags: graylog

I'm running a graylog collector sidecar (https://github.com/digiapulssi/graylog-sidecar) to send logs to my graylog. The collector is running successfully and I'm able to see the logs in my web interface.

I'm collecting logs from several sources-I have tagged them accordingly (syslog, apache, kafka, etc).

Question: Is there any way to know which tag triggers the collection of the message? For every message I see information like

tags
["apache","kafka","syslog"]

I'm really new to graylog...

Comment: I'd recommend posting this questions in the official Graylog community forums: https://community.graylog.org/

Comment: Thx! I was not aware of it!